# How to sort in Mongo depending on the result of a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am developing a web-app in MEAN stack (my back-end code runs in NodeJS server) for registering the assets of my network. I have the `data` collection inside my database, which comprises of some entries. One of the fields of each entry is `ip` field. My final goal is to sort by IP.

`ip` field values are *strings*. If I use the `sort({ ip : 1 })`, I will have the following problem: the entry with ip *192.168.1.145* will appear before entry with ip *192.168.1.2*, because comparing becomes digit by digit.

So, to overcome this problem, I thought to transform each IP in a form like *192.168.001.145* and *192.168.001.002*. I want this transformation to become only during the sorting process and to avoid adding another field or just save the data in that form in the IP field.

So far, I have:

```
//------------ Get all entries, sorted by IP  ------------
router.get('/getEntriesSortedByIP', (req, res, next) => {
    db.get().collection('data')
            .find()
            .sort(function(u) {          
                    if (u.ip != '') {   
                        let ip_part = u.ip.split('.');
                        while (ip_part[0].length < 3) {          
                            ip_part[0] = '0' + ip_part[0];  
                        }
                        while (ip_part[1].length < 3) {          
                            ip_part[1] = '0' + ip_part[1];  
                        }
                        while (ip_part[2].length < 3) {          
                            ip_part[2] = '0' + ip_part[2];  
                        }
                        while (ip_part[3].length < 3) {          
                            ip_part[3] = '0' + ip_part[3];  
                        }
                        u.ip = ip_part[0] + '.' + ip_part[1] + '.' + ip_part[2] + '.' + ip_part[3];
                    }
                    return u; 
                 })
            .toArray((err, data) => {    
                if (err) { return res.send(err) }
                res.json(data);
            });
});
```

The tranformation is successful. The only problem is that the sorting is not happening.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking to do a client-side sort, call `sort` on the `data` array instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about MonogBD solution:

Split `ip` field into 4 temp fields. We convert `String` into `Integer`. Now we sort by temporal variables. At the end, with `$unset` we remove from result temp variables.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      ip1: {
        $toInt: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$ip",
                "."
              ]
            },
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      ip2: {
        $toInt: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$ip",
                "."
              ]
            },
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      ip3: {
        $toInt: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$ip",
                "."
              ]
            },
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      ip4: {
        $toInt: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $split: [
                "$ip",
                "."
              ]
            },
            3
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      ip1: 1,
      ip2: 1,
      ip3: 1,
      ip4: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "ip1",
      "ip2",
      "ip3",
      "ip4"
    ]
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eGD3Jnu6NLH)

Comment: It works only for 3 new fields. If I added the fourth new field, no sorting would happen. Why is this happening?

Comment: UPDATE: For some reason, it works only for `{$split: ["$ip","."]} , 1` , `{$split: ["$ip","."]} , 2` and `{$split: ["$ip","."]} , 3`. When I use `{$split: ["$ip","."]} , 0`, data doesn't return. Why is this happening?

Comment: @kostas_me_ can you post ip adress where spliting fails?